# Limiting Prolog solutions based on rules

Tags: prolog

I have a Prolog program that says whether people like various types of fruit:

```
likes(alice,apple).
likes(bob,peach).
likes(bob,pear).
```

There are a number of these types of fruit available:

```
count(apple,1).
count(peach,2).
count(pear,6).
```

A user can each fruit if they like the fruit and there is enough of their liked fruit available:

```
can_eat(Person,Fruit) :- likes(Person, Fruit),
    count(Fruit,N),
    N > 0.
```

So you can do:

```
?- can_eat(X,Y).
X = bob,
Y = apple ;  <-- single apple
X = bob,
Y = peach ;
X = alice,
Y = apple.  <-- single apple, again
```

or

```
?- can_eat(alice,X).
X = apple. <-- Alice has apple

?- can_eat(bob,X).
X = apple ; <-- Bob has apple
X = peach.
```

Both Alice and Bob are allowed the apple but **there is only one apple**.  How can I tell Prolog that only Alice or Bob are allowed the apple, not both.  I think I need a way of keeping track of the number of apples that are left depending on the solution Prolog is giving me.

Comment: Please explain what the people in your example are supposed to do. "All you can eat" for everybody?

Answer (score 1):

You can represent the set of available fruits and make relations update it according to the actions performed by people.  Something along `can_eat(Person, Fruit, Env)` where `Env` contains `(Fruit, Count)` couples, for example.

An updated environment `New_Env` is based on an old one where for some old `(Fruit, X)`, there is a `(Fruit, Y)` item where `Y` is `X - 1`. You could represent this relation with [clpfd](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html), `Y #= X - 1`, and `Y #>= 0`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should post your exact database, since right now bob doesn't like apples. So we get

```
?- setof(F-P, can_eat(F,P), L).
L = [alice-apple, bob-peach, bob-pear].
```

Anyway, as long as can_eat/2 arguments are *atomic*, there is no way to solve your problem. The required interpretation implies a change of state, an assignment.

For instance

```
can_eat(A) :-
    findall(F-N, count(F, N), L),
    assign(L, A).

assign(L, [P-Fruit|As]) :-
    likes(P, Fruit),
    select(Fruit-N, L, R),
    N > 0, M is N-1,
    assign([Fruit-M|R], As).
assign(_, []).
```

that yields a long solution list,exactly

```
?- aggregate(count,A^can_eat(A),N).
N = 945.
```